# How to retrieve contact names which contain a specific word in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, android-contacts

Imagine the following phonebook:

**A**

123456

**B with Android**

654321

**C**

112233

**D with Android**

778899

I want to retrieve the contacts containig "with Android". The idea is to use "with Android" as a selection criterion.

I have tried the following:

```
String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
String selection = " with Android";
String[] selectionArgs = {selection};
Cursor myCursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
        projection, where, selectionArgs, null);
```

I have also tried using **" =?"** instead of **" LIKE ?"** but did not got the result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try "LIKE % with Android"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am also a newbie in android, but i think this may help you

Actually the query string you are trying to fetch the matching string is wrong.
When using like...if you want to fetch certain strings matching a certain text, you need to specify the query string as:-

```
SELECT * FROM customers
WHERE 'Robert Bob Smith III, PhD.' LIKE '%mit%';
```

In android, the selection arguments are passed as a string array

Change your code like this:

```
String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ";
String selection = "%with Android";
String[] selectionArgs = {selection};
```

Please check it out

Comment: I tried it and got an error: 09-23 17:48:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(5654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 17:48:30.517: E/AndroidRuntime(5654): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT display_name, data1 FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1 AND mimetype_id=5) AND ((display_name LIKE)) I am really confused what could the error be.

Comment: try adding ** ?** after 'LIKE'

Comment: I've just tested and It worked!!! Unfortunately i can not upvote because i don't have reputation higher than 15, sorry :(